# Facebook - Allow User to specify username

Tags: facebook

I am creating a site that I want to use Facebook login solely for convenience. People coming to my site will want to be anonymous and not use their real names.

I used Facebook connect on a site in the last 6 months that asked me to input a username after I filled in my Facebook login credentials (It was still in the Facebook connect box).

I have not seen it since and am trying to explain it to a developer. Does anybody know about this, or how to achieve it?

Comment: what do you exactly want? you haven't stated that clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the webapp in question authenticated against FB Connect, and then used some piece of information returned (uid, probably) to create an entry in the site's user database, which also allowed for a username to be used on the site, rather than just using the person's name as supplied via FB.

Comment: This is a better explanation of the question, but not necessarily an answer.